# Como gerar container do grafana corretamente?

Tags: docker

Instalei o container do grafana via docker da seguinte forma :

```
docker run -d --name=grafana \
--restart always \
-p 5000:3000 \
-e "GF_SERVER_PROTOCOL=http" \
-e "GF_SERVER_ROOT_URL=http://meuIP" \
-e "GF_SERVER_HTTP_PORT=3000" \
-v /docker/grafana/data:/var/lib/grafana \
grafana/grafana
```

Mas quando eu tento acessar ele não vai pois não esta rodando no IP que eu quero ( meuIP) e sim no `0.0.0.0` como mostrado abaixo :

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED              STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
2c7246e98d99        grafana/grafana     "/run.sh"           About a minute ago   Up 4 seconds        0.0.0.0:5000->3000/tcp   grafana
```

Neste caso como eu faço para rotear e acessar ele digitando http://meuIP:5000 no navegador ?

**EDITADO :**

Estou usando o CentOS7.

A versão do Docker é :

```
Client:
 Version:      17.05.0-ce
 API version:  1.29
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   89658be
 Built:        Thu May  4 22:06:25 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.05.0-ce
 API version:  1.29 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   89658be
 Built:        Thu May  4 22:06:25 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
```

**Editado 2 :**

O problema é que de uma hora pra outra o container fica com status `Exited (1)` segundos depois de eu rodar.

Se faço assim ele roda e consigo acessar :

```
docker run \
  -d \
  -p 5200:3000 \
  grafana/grafana
```

Mas eu quero instalar o plugin do zabbix também. Ai se eu faço assim ele exita após 10 segundos:

```
docker run -d \
-p 5100:3000 \
-e "GF_INSTALL_PLUGINS=alexanderzobnin-zabbix-app" \
grafana/grafana
```

Também quero redirecionar os dados do container para uma pasta específica para se der algo de errado eu poder recuperar .

Se faço assim ele também excita:

```
docker run \
  -d \
  -p 5200:3000 \
   -v /docker/grafana/data:/var/lib/grafana \
  grafana/grafana
```

Mas eu queria era fazer assim :

```
docker run -d \
-p 5100:3000 \
-e "GF_INSTALL_PLUGINS=alexanderzobnin-zabbix-app" \
-v /docker/grafana/data:/var/lib/grafana \
grafana/grafana
```

Alguém sabe por que o container fica sendo cancelado quando eu tento instalar o plugin ou redirecionar a saída ?

Comment: Faz um teste da seguinte forma: `docker run -d  -p 3000:3000 grafana/grafana`. Após isso tenta acessar  `http://localhost:3000` e me fala se consegue acessar.

Comment: @Tuxpilgrim, sim  tentei mas também não funciona.

Comment: No Linux. Mais precisamente no CentOS 7.

Comment: Editei a pergunta para adicionar mais informações.

Comment: Editei novamente a pergunta.

Comment: Sugiro que edite o título da pergunta, o problema aparentemente não tem mais relação com acessar o endereço do *container*.

Comment: Título editado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tendo em vista seu cenário, recomendaria criar uma imagem personalizada com o(s) plugin(s) que precisa, facilita ao invés de executar esse comando grande sempre que for *startar* seu *container*.

#### Configurando o `Dockerfile`

No repositório do [grafana](https://github.com/grafana/grafana-docker/) tem um diretório `custom/`com um `Dockerfile` para personalizar, basta fazer o [clone](https://github.com/grafana/grafana-docker.git) e usar.

#### Construindo a imagem

Dentro do diretório clonado (`grafana-docker/custom/`), construa a nova imagem passando por parâmetro:

- a versão da imagem do grafana usada como base, na variável `GRAFANA_VERSION`
- e o(s) plugins que deseja instalar na variável `GF_INSTALL_PLUGINS`

Algo assim:

```
docker build -t grafana:atual_com_plugins \
  --build-arg "GRAFANA_VERSION=latest" \
  --build-arg "GF_INSTALL_PLUGINS=alexanderzobnin-zabbix-app" .
```

**Dica¹:** Ao invés de usar a *tag* `latest` use sempre a última versão estável, no caso a versão [`v5.1.0`](https://hub.docker.com/r/grafana/grafana/).

#### Iniciando o *container*

Com a sua imagem construída com sucesso, pode iniciar normalmente:

```
docker run \
  -d \
  -p 5200:3000 \
  --name=grafana \
   -v /docker/grafana/data:/var/lib/grafana \
  grafana:atual_com_plugins
```

Todas essas informações estão disponíveis na documentação de [instalação com docker](http://docs.grafana.org/installation/docker/).

**Obs:** se ainda assim não funcionar, verifique se o *plugin* está ok ou se não é problema com as versões do grafana estão sem problema.

**EDIT:** Como citado pelo @beto, caso queira persistir os dados usando volume, é necessário dar permissão no diretório onde vão ser guardados os dados.

Comment: Funcionou. Tinha que gerar os pugins com o dockerfile do grafana mesmo. Também tem que dar permissão na pasta do host que vai guardar os dados do container do grafana para o container executar, caso se queira fazer dessa forma.